# zeroMQ client exercise separating interface from implementation

Tags: c++, zeromq

I am testing the examples of the ZeroMQ framework asynchronous library messaging to work in distributed applications, enabling the interoperability between programming languages.

I write the following C++ client code [based in this code](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient)

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main ()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    struct timeval t_ini, t_fin;

    gettimeofday(&t_ini, NULL);

    cout << "Connecting to zeroMQ python server" << endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    // Send data to server socket
    zmq::message_t request (20);
    memcpy (request.data (), "Hola Servidor Python", 20);
    socket.send (request);

    // Getting reply form zeroMQ python server
    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv (&reply);
    string replyMessage = string(static_cast<char *>(reply.data()), reply.size());

    cout << "Getting reply form zeroMQ python server: " + replyMessage << " "  << endl;

    gettimeofday(&t_fin, NULL);

    printf("Tiempo en microsegundos: %ld microsegundos\n",
           ((t_fin.tv_sec - t_ini.tv_sec)*1000000L
           +t_fin.tv_usec) -t_ini.tv_usec
          );
    return 0;

}
```

This c++ client code it's works

My objective is rewrite the previous code separating interface from implementation making use of C++ headers files.

I have the `client.h` file in which I define the `class Client`

```
#ifndef ZEROMQ_CLASS_CLIENT_H
#define ZEROMQ_CLASS_CLIENT_H
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;

class Client{
public:
    Client();
    void setupConnection();

private:
    //zmq::context_t context (1);
    //zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    struct timeval t_before, t_after;
    string replyMessage;

};

#endif //ZEROMQ_CLASS_CLIENT_H
```

I have the `client.cpp` file in which I develop my `setupConnection()` members function

```
#include "client.h"
#include <zmq.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;



Client::Client(){

};

void Client::setupConnection(){

    gettimeofday(&t_before, NULL);

    cout << "Connecting to python zeroMQ server ..."<<endl;
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    zmq::message_t request (20);
    memcpy(request.data(), "Hello Python server", 20);
    socket.send(request);

    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv(&reply);
    replyMessage = string(static_cast<char *>(reply.data()), reply.size());

    cout << "Getting response from server: " + replyMessage << " " << endl;
    gettimeofday(&t_after, NULL);

    printf("Time in microseconds: %ld microseconds\n",
           ((t_after.tv_sec - t_before.tv_sec)*1000000L
            +t_before.tv_usec) -t_before.tv_usec
    );
}
```

And in the `main.cpp` file I create the object and call to the function:

```
#include "client.h"

int main() {
    Client c;
    c.setupConnection();
    return 0;
}
```

When I build the `main.cpp` file, I get this message:

```
% g++ main.cpp -o client.out -lzmq
/tmp/cc8hDANf.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Client::Client()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `Client::setupConnection()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, any idea?

Comment: You need to include *all* `.cpp` files in your build. Since you have more than one `.cpp` file you'll need to compile them separately, then link together in a final pass. A good `Makefile` template can fix this, of which there are innumerable variants.

Comment: Hi @tadman  I am few newbie in C++ How to can I build a good Makefile template. Do you have some good resource to read and understand. I know that in Internet there is a ton of it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you don't compile `client.cpp`. Including `client.hpp` is not enough (obviously this is a separate file and your compiler does not assume that there is a corresponding `.cpp` file.) Try adding `client.cpp` to your gcc command, i.e. `g++ main.cpp client.cpp -lzmq`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't compiling client.cpp:

g++ main.cpp client.cpp -o client.out -lzmq